# JavaFX - Show cells in empty table

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, when a table has no data, there is no grid shown, instead it is a white plane saying "No content in table".

What do I have to do if I want the common grid, just with no content instead of the white plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using two tricks:

1. I added one entry to the table with empty values in order to make sure the grid is shown.
2. I set setMouseTransparent(true) so the first entry is not clickable and the table really acts as if nothing is there.